# problem in updaing table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```sql
select * from student
update student
set name = 'Ronald'
where ID = 2;
```

Gives

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "student"
LINE 2: update student
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the SELECT if you want to update a row:

```
update student
  set name = 'Ronald'
where id = 2;
```

More details [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

Comment: thank you it worked